# Using Leaflet.PolylineDecorator I got read property 'dash' of undefined

Tags: javascript, leaflet

In  Laravel 6/blade/jquery 3/leaflet app I want to add direction icons to
Polyline with https://github.com/bbecquet/Leaflet.PolylineDecorator
I installed it with npm and in resources/js/app.js I imported leaflet:

```
require('./bootstrap');

require('jquery');

window.Vue = require('vue');
export const bus = new Vue()

import 'leaflet-polylinedecorator';
import 'leaflet-rotatedmarker';
```

But I got error

```
 Cannot read property 'dash' of undefined
```

trying to use in blade form example :

```
@section('scripts')

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css"
          integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
          crossorigin=""/>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js"
            integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew=="
            crossorigin=""></script>


    <script>


            var polyline = new L.Polyline(polylinePoints, {
            });
            polyline.addTo(mymap);
             var decorator = L.polylineDecorator(polyline, {
                patterns: [
                    {offset: 0, repeat: 20, symbol: L.Symbol.dash({pixelSize: 10})}
                ]
            }).addTo(mymap);

            // zoom the map to the polyline
            mymap.fitBounds(polyline.getBounds());
```

In console I see that L.Symbol is undefined.

What did I miss ?

**MODIFIED :**
Googling I found a possible decision to add in resources/js/app.js :

```
import * as L from 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet-polylinedecorator';
```

But it did not help me and I still have the same error.

Can it be that I have to add import lines in some other way, not in resources/js/app.js.
But I do not know how add import in bade file, as trying to make :

```
<script>
    import * as L from 'leaflet';
    import 'leaflet-polylinedecorator';
```

I got error :

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
```

Which is valid way ?

Thanks!

Comment: Pls, look at MODIFIED